# How to fill missing dates by ID in a table in sql

Tags: sql, database, date, join, sql-insert

I have table A which has Dates and EMPID eg below

```
date          EMPID     
8/06/19        1
8/07/19        1         
8/08/19        1         
8/09/19        1        
8/07/19        2          
8/09/19        2        
8/12/19        2
```

I also have Table B which has a date range

```
date
...        
8/05/19
8/06/19
8/07/19
8/08/19
8/09/19
8/10/19
8/11/19
8/12/19
8/13/19
...
```

My table A has missing dates and EMPID.

How can I merge the two tables to have the following table.

```
Date           EMPID
8/05/19        1
8/06/19        1
8/07/19        1
8/08/19        1
8/09/19        1
8/10/19        1
8/11/19        1
8/12/19        1
8/13/19        1
8/05/19        2
8/06/19        2
8/07/19        2
8/08/19        2
8/09/19        2
8/10/19        2
8/11/19        2
8/12/19        2
8/13/19        2
```

Thanks in advance.
This is being used in a dataset(SQL) in SSRS.
P.S. I'm new to coding in SQL environment, My background is in ABAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `cross join` the distinct `empid` coming from `a` with dates coming from `b`, as follows:

```
select b.date, a.empid
from (select distinct empid from a) a
cross join b
```

Or if you are looking to `insert` "missing" dates in `a`, then you can use the `insert ... select` syntax with a `not exists` condition:

```
insert into a (date, empid)
select b.date, a.empid
from (select distinct empid from a) a
cross join b 
where not exists (select 1 from a a1 where a1.empid = a.empid and a1.date = b.date)
```